# how do I fix "E/MediaPlayerNative: attachNewPlayer called in state 16"

Tags: android

I am trying to make a audio streaming program and right now I can click the play button to play the audio and change the button's image to pause image, but the program won't let me click the pause button to pause the audio.

I also got this error messages:

> E/MediaPlayerNative: attachNewPlayer called in state 16
>
> 2072-2093/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

```
private static final String TAG = "ItemActivity";
    Button playBtn;
    Button pauseBtn;
    Button genreBtn;
    SeekBar positionBar;
    TextView elapsedTimeLabel;
    TextView remainingTimeLabel;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int TotalTime;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
        getIncomingIntent();

        playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        elapsedTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elapsedTimeLabel);
        remainingTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeLabel);

        genreBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genreBtn);

        // Media Player


    }

    private void getIncomingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: checking for incoming intents.");
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("bookimage")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("booktitle")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("bookauthor")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("bookseries")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("bookaudio")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("bookgenre")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: found intent extras.");

            String bookimage = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookimage");
            String booktitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("booktitle");
            String bookauthor = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookauthor");
            String bookseries = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookseries");
            String bookaudio = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookaudio");
            String bookgenre = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookgenre");

            setImage(bookimage, booktitle, bookauthor, bookseries, bookaudio, bookgenre);
        }
    }

    private void setImage(String bookimage, String booktitle, String bookauthor, String bookseries, final String bookaudio, final String bookgenre) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting the image and name to widgets.");

        TextView title = findViewById(R.id.activityitem_textView);
        title.setText(booktitle);
        TextView author = findViewById(R.id.activityitem_textView2);
        author.setText(bookauthor);
        TextView series = findViewById(R.id.activityitem_textView3);
        series.setText(bookseries);

        final TextView genre = findViewById(R.id.activityitem_textView4);
        genre.setText(bookgenre);

        Button genreBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genreBtn);
        if (bookgenre.equals("Action & Adventure")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.knight);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Animals & Nature")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paw);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Arts & Entertainment")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color_palette);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Biographies & Memoirs")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notebook);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Comics")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comic);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Early Learning")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.idea);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Education")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graduation);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Fiction")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quill);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("History")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.papyrus);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Mystery & Thrillers")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.magnifying_glass);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Religious & Spirituality")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp);
            //Needs Change//
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Romance")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Science Fiction & Fantasy")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planet);
        } else if (bookgenre.equals("Sports")){
            genreBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.basketball);
        }

        genreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ItemActivity.this, bookgenre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.activityitem_imageView);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(bookimage)
                .into(image);

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(final View view) {

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bookaudio);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                            if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                                mp.pause();
                                playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                            }


                            else if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
                                mp.start();
                                playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                            }
                        }


                    });

                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        });


    }


}
```